# Is $H_0^1$ something reasonable for the electric field for a perfect conductor?

Tags: mathematical-physics, maxwell-equations

I'm trying to pull over some concepts that were derived for Navier-Stokes like equations to Maxwell's equations for the perfect conductor.

At a certain point, I am about to assume that the electric field $\mathbf E$ is in the Sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$, i.e. $E$ is differentiable wrt. the space variables and $E=0$ at the boundary.

This is different from the common assumptions that locate $\mathbf E$ in $H_0(curl;\Omega)$, i.e. $\mathbf E$ is a bit less smooth and only its tangential component, namely $n\times E=0$, is zero at the boundary.

Since $H_0^1(\Omega) \subset H_0(curl;\Omega)$, my assumption is more restrictive.

**My question**: Does the assumption that $E=0$ at the boundary exclude common types of electrical fields?

I am concerned about the condition that $E=0$ on the boundary, rather than about the additional smoothness. In other words: Is it reasonable to assume that a magnetic field is zero at a boundary.

Comment: It is by no means obvious how to physically impose $E=0$ on the boundary, in practice. The weaker condition you mention is true in common situations, if the boundary is a conductor...

Comment: A charged conductor has a non 0 E at the surface.

Comment: Furthermore, in the absence of charge in $\Omega$, your condition implies that E vanishes in the same set if passing to the potential. This way you disregard too many physically important situations.

Comment: I see. If you make your comments an answer I can accept it. And I will look for better assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is by no means obvious how to physically impose ${\bf E}={\bf 0}$ on the boundary, in practice. Instead, the weaker condition you mention is true in common situations, if the boundary of $\Omega$ is that of a conductor in particular.
Furthermore, in the absence of charge in $\Omega$, your condition (under suitably hypotheses on $\Omega$) implies that ${\bf E}$ vanishes in $\Omega$ when  passing to deal with the potential. This way you lose too many physically important situations.